# Checkbox event handling

Tags: c#, winforms, checkbox

I have a MyControl class. Inside MyClass object there are textboxes and a checkbox.

I am trying to add a checkbox event handler, but it does not work. What can be the problem?

```
private List<MyControls> _myControls = new List<MyControls>();
MyControls mc = new MyControls();

public void CreateFormElements(int i, StringReader sr)
{
    ProductForm form2 = new ProductForm();
    form2.Visible = true;
    form2.Activate();
    String line = "";

    for (int n = 0; n < i; n++)
    {
        line = sr.ReadLine();
        mc = new MyControls();

        if (line.Length > 3)
        {
            String[] _line = line.Split(new char[] { '\t' });
            mc.SetY(30 + n * 20);
            mc.initElements(_line, n);
            _myControls.Add(mc);
            **mc.cb.CheckedChanged += cb_CheckedChanged;**
        }
    }
}


private void cb_CheckedChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string NameSet  = (sender as CheckBox).Name.Split(new char[]{'_'})[1];
    MessageBox.Show(NameSet);
}
```

Here is the code of MyControls Class:

```
class MyControls
{
    int x=5;
    int y=30;
    public CheckBox cb = new CheckBox();
    public TextBox tb1 = new TextBox();

    public TextBox tbSpecs = new TextBox();
    public TextBox tb3 = new TextBox();
    public TextBox tb4 = new TextBox();

    public void initElements(String[] name, int i)
    {
        cb.Width = 10;
        cb.Height = 10;
        cb.Name = "cb_" + i.ToString();
        cb.Location = new Point(x, y+5);
        cb.Checked = false;
        Form.ActiveForm.Controls.Add(cb);

        x += 15;

        tb1.Width = 50;
        tb1.Height = 20;
        tb1.Location = new Point(x, y);
        tb1.Name = "tb1_" + i.ToString();
        tb1.Text = name[0];
        Form.ActiveForm.Controls.Add(tb1);
        x += 60;

        tbSpecs.Width = 150;
        tbSpecs.Height = 20;
        tbSpecs.Name = "tb2_" + i.ToString();
        tbSpecs.Text = name[1];
        tbSpecs.Location = new Point(x, y);
        Form.ActiveForm.Controls.Add(tbSpecs);
        x += 160;

        tb3.Width = 40;
        tb3.Height = 20;
        tb3.Name = "tb3_" + i.ToString();
        tb3.Text = name[2];
        tb3.Location = new Point(x, y);
        Form.ActiveForm.Controls.Add(tb3);
        x += 50;

        tb4.Width = 450;
        tb4.Height = 20;
        tb4.Name = "tb4_" + i.ToString();
        tb4.Text = name[3];
        tb4.Location = new Point(x, y);
        Form.ActiveForm.Controls.Add(tb4);

        x = 0;
    }

    public int SetX(int X)
    {
        x = X;
        return x;
    }

    public int SetY(int Y)
    {
        y = Y;
        return y;
    }
}
```

Comment: MyControls.cs is a class. It holds 4 textboxes and 1 checkbox in it. I am now adding it

Comment: David, when I click the checkbox, I want checkbox function to run. But it does not work.

Comment: Is this winforms or webforms?

Comment: A pet peeve of mine but totally off topic -- The argument to String.Split() is "params char[]", so you don't need to actually build a new char array.  You can just do str.Split('_');

Comment: Have you put a break point on the first line of cb_CheckedChanged? Does it get here and then throw an exception perhaps?

Comment: Along a similar vein, does this line `mc.cb.CheckedChanged += cb_CheckedChanged;` ever get hit?

Comment: Joey, it never gets hit. This is my problem.

Comment: There is something strange occured Joey. I added a breakpoint at mc.cb.CheckedChanged += cb_CheckedChanged; and run it and remove the breakpoint and run again and now everything works fine!!! I dont know what happened but now the code is working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
mc.cb.CheckedChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.cb_CheckedChanged)
```

Comment: You cannot directly assign a delegate but have to go through an EventHandler.

Comment: The compiler will implicitly do this for you as far as I'm aware.

Answer (score 0):

A few points to check in `CreateFormElements(int i, StringReader sr){...}`:

Is `i` greater than zero? If not the loop will never run and the event handler will never get attached.

Is `line.Length` ever greater than zero? If not you'll never get inside the if-block and the handler won't get attached.

Comment: problem solved Joey thanks now I got another problem :) soon I will post it. I need to change locations of textboxes...